# Calculate row wise least squares

Tags: r

I would like to do the following and not sure how to (very new to R programming!)

I want to calculate least squares measure (as defined in the code below) between the numeric vector ('values') and each row in the data frame ('df').

I came up with the way that requires me to change the row manually (see 'dat').

How can I make R to calculate the LS from each row and creating a new column to df that stores the LS value for the corresponding row?

(I have a large data frame so basically can't do this manually)

```
# Dataframe

df <-data.frame(col1=c(1:10),
                   col2=c(2:11),
                   col3=c(3:12))

# num vector 
values <- c(0.2, 0.5, 1.2)

#Calculate the least squares  
dat <- df[1,1:3]
LS<- sum((values-dat)^2)
```

Comment: Question: you have 3 elements in your values vector, but you are subtracting 2 values from the df data frame when estimating LS (the [,2:3] part)?

Comment: true, edited that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
df$LS=apply(df,1,function(x){
  sum((values-x)^2)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a large number of columns, you can also try a `dplyr` solution like this:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(temp1 = (values[1]-col1)^2,
         temp2 = (values[2]-col2)^2,
         temp3 = (values[3]-col3)^2,
         LS = sum(temp1, temp2, temp3)) %>%
  select(-temp1, -temp2, -temp3)
```